# FastAPI endpoint treating a dependency as a Depends object rather than the yielded value

Tags: fastapi, psycopg2

I have a dependency that looks as such:

```
def get_connection_from_pool():
    conn = pool.getconn()
    yield conn
    pool.putconn(conn)
```

It's a fairly simple dependency which just pulls a connection from a connection pool (created on app start up) and yields it to the endpoint and then puts the connection back once the endpoint is complete.

The endpoint looks as such:

```
@auth.post(path="/login")
def login(
        email: EmailStr = Form(default=Required),
        pass_hash: str = Form(default=Required),
        db_connection: Connection = Depends(get_connection_from_pool)
):
    print(type(db_connection))
    with db_connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Login logic
```

The print statement correctly prints out '<class psycopg.Connection >' but then, when I try to open a cursor, I get an error saying that the Depends object has no attribute 'cursor'

What I'm guessing is that fastapi is treating db_connection as a Depends object and not a psycopg.Connection object which is confusing me because the print statement tells me the exact opposite. Any ideas as to why this could be happening ?

Comment: Is the error actually trigged by _those lines_ and not by what your login logic is? i.e. what is the logic you're calling? Does the call happen to another class/service that also have a `Depends`? Then it won't get resolved, and you end up with the Depends-object directly. Dependencies are resolved from the controller arguments and through the hierarchy, but if you have a second function that you're calling inside your login logic that have a `Depends` - it won't get resolved, as that part is never handled by FastAPI. For a dependency to be resolved, it has to be part of what FastAPI handles.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue that was occurring. Later on in the login logic, I was calling another function whose signature looked like this:

```
def create_jwt_token(user_id: int, connection: Connection = Depends(get_connection_from_pool)):
```

Since this method isn't a FastAPI method and falls outside the scope of FastAPI, that Depends object isn't resolved and causes the `Depends has no attribute cursor`. Any method outside the scope of FastAPI won't resolve the Depends object as per what the dependency returns/yields. For more information, check out this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1105). Special thanks to @MatsLindh for pointing out the flaw!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem before, when the function including a `yield` statement, the function becomes a generator function and returns a generator object when called.

So in your code, `get_connection_from_pool()` is returning a generator object that yields a connection object.

```
from psycopg2.extensions import connection

def get_connection_from_pool() -> connection:
    conn = pool.getconn()
    try:
        yield conn
    finally:
        pool.putconn(conn)
```

This modified code tells `FastAPI` that the function it needs to return a `psycopg2.extensions.connection` object.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have resolved the issue. Same error as before. On another note, if it had returned a generator object, would the print statement express that in the endpoint ?

Comment: Is the connection still open when you create the cursor?

Comment: Type hints are not used during runtime, they are meant to write more explicit code to help developers.

Comment: @Simon While true for regular code running under cpython, they're explicitly used for specific functionality in FastAPI (such as output/input (de)serialization). It shouldn't be an issue in this case, however.

Comment: @MatsLindh in FastAPI, parameter type hints are indeed used in route methods annotated by @router.get/post etc, but method return type hints are never used. Route responses can be validated and serialized by using response_model. But in this case, get_connection_from_pool is no route method and therefore the type hints are not used during runtime.

Comment: @Simon return type hints became an alternative to `response_model` on the decorator in 0.95 (iirc): https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/ - my point is just that they _can_ be used runtime if the library utilizes them, so that OP doesn't get the wrong impression that they're irrelevant in their project.

Comment: @MatsLindh that's new to me, cool! I think the main takeaway here is that the type annotations are only relevant due to FastAPI's @app.get/post etc decorators, apart from those they are irrelevant during runtime.